# Magento 2.3 has stopped Wysiwyg(Tinymce) editor working after upfrade from magento 2.2.x

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I have upgraded to magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.0, it upgraded successfully. 
But there i am getting issue with Wysiwyg(Tinymce) editor. 
At admin panel, category edit page and product edit page i am getting following error.

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://example.com/pub/static/version1545219436/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.

Please help me how can i fix it.
Thank you

Comment: does the file exist?  have you checked the path.  if it doesnt, do a static content deploy, if it does, check permissions

Comment: Hello PixieMedia, I checked on magento 2.3.0 fresh installation. There they don't call this tinymce.js file.  On magento 2.3.0(Fresh)  & after upgrade they both call tinymce.min.js file. But our after upgraded version calls tinymce.js file also.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, i found how to solve it.
There is a problem, that composer while upgrade didn't delete root_dir/lib folder as i understand. So, old code that use tinymce v3 still called and executed. To fix it just run from magento_root_dir:

```
rm -rf lib/web ; rm -rf vendor ; composer i
```

It solved this issue for me.

Comment: Did this and it made it worse by adding a jquery error to the mix. Did not fix.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at acceptData (jquery.js:3)

en_US/tinymce.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce

Comment: Sorry for no response for so long but I don't think that problem that something was deleted that shouldn't. Did you fix it? Can you tell me about the problem's reason? It seems like some elements not rendered on a page.